# .NET 4.5.1 are only for windows 8?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project that I change the .NET target from 4.0 to 4.5.1, so when I try to install MVVM Light, it install the version 5 of the framework. In the description says that is for windows 8, not says nothing about windows 7, soI have doubts.

If I go to he downlad center of Microsoft, if I search for .NET 4.5.1 I find this page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643

In System requirements says that is compatible with windows 7 sp1.

However, in this another link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx says that only the version 4.5 is compatible with windows 7 and 4.5.1 are only compatible with windows 8.

So I would like to know if it's possible to execute a .NET 4.5.1 application on windows 7 or not.

Thanks.

Comment: .net 4.5.1 is definitely compatible with Windows 7, if it is not compatible then you are not able to install it.

Comment: The page you're looking at does *not* say 4.5.1 is only compatible with Windows 8. It says it's *included* with Windows 8.1. Which bit of the page made you think it's "only compatible with Windows 8"?

Comment: Your second link says "Windows 8 and earlier" where Windows 7 is included in earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For end-users, Windows Vista is the minimum requirement. So it also works on Windows 7, 8, 8.1.

For Windows desktop application/Web developers, Windows 7 is the minimum requirement to install Windows SDK and Visual Studio 2012/2013 for development.

Answer (score 1):

The second link describes the fact that 4.5 & 4.5.1 are bundled with Windows 8/8.1.

The compatibility table is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx